# docker: invalid reference format. See 'docker run --help'

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to serving my model using TensorFlow with docker. I downloaded Docker for windows and tried the code as per the documentation.

```
!docker pull tensorflow/serving
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving
TESTDATA="/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata"
```

Above code worked fine .But when i tried below code

```
 !docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501,-v "TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two",-e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two,tensorflow/serving
```

It is giving below error.

```
docker: invalid reference format.See 'docker run --help'..
```

Any idea guys please help.

Comment: Probably best to ask on Stackoverflow in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

@BSP This worked for me:

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 -v "$testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" -e "MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two" tensorflow/serving
```

Comment: Provided that "testdata" variable = "$PWD/..."